# determine which permutation of sorting sorts an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

So given array A = [3,2,6], with A[1]= 3, A[2] = 2, A[3] = 6, after sorting we have A=[2,3,6], which gives the permutation P = [2,1,3].

What's an algorithm (the faster the better) that returns this array P?

I'm thinking of just making every element in the unsorted array A a pair, with the index as the second element of the pair. I'll make a list and fill in the tuples. After I sort the list by value (using some stable sort), the indices would move accordingly to give me the right array P. Is this the right way to proceed, or is there a better way?

Comment: You could create a second array `index[]` which initially will contain `[1, 2, 3, ...]`.  At each sorting step, you would also move the elements in the `index[]` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way (in most programming languages) is to construct an array of indexes, and sort them, using the original array in the comparator.

For example, in Python:

```
A = [3, 2, 6]
sorted(range(3), key=lambda i: A[i])

output:
[1, 0, 2]
```

Note that here the indices are 0-based rather than 1-based in your question, so the output is `[1, 0, 2]` and not `[2, 1, 3]`. Very few current programming languages have 1-based indexes, although there are some.

Your suggestion of decorating the input with indices, sorting it, and then removing the original values works fine too, although I'd personally prefer to sort the indices directly as in the first method.

```
[j for _, j in sorted(zip([3, 2, 6], range(3)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most built-in sorting functions give you a way to specify a custom key comparison. You can use this to add a level of indirection. Create an array P that starts out initially as [1,2,3], and sort it. Have the custom comparator actually compare `A[P[x]]` to `A[P[y]]` instead of the default `P[x]` to `P[y]`.